# AWS Route53 Aliasing

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment running my website. There's an existing domain which I would like to use for the AWS-hosted website. So far I've got it working by copying the four AWS Route53 name server entries to my domain registrar. The only problem I am having is that instead of using the domain I get redirected to the `example.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` domain. I would like the original domain to 'stay' in the url bar of my browser. I have created an Alias targeting `example.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` in Route53.

Do I have to use a CNAME entry?

Comment: Is your website something like WordPress? The redirect is likely coming from your code, not Route53/EB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the redirect entirely in WordPress is one option, but do consider [changing the site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) to the correct one (i.e. the actual domain).

This will ensure users who stumble across the `example.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` URL get redirected to the right URL.

Comment: I am going to have multiple domains pointing to the server i. e. example.com and example.org and so on. what should my site url be?

Comment: @mo_st That depends a bit. If they're all for the same site, you should have the other domains redirect to the main, "canonical" one so Google doesn't penalize you for duplicate content.

Comment: there are going to be different domains for different countries for example .uk, .us  and so on. I would prefer, if users trying to access example.us stay on example.us instead of getting redirected to example.com

Comment: There are various approaches to that. https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain-mapping-on-single-site/ https://myjeeva.com/mapping-multiple-domains-into-single-instance-of-wordpress.html

Answer (score 1):

The redirect was coming from Wordpress - thanks ceejayoz for your guess

Solution

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71927/how-to-prevent-automatic-redirection